# ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)

Tags: python

I try to export random proxy from a webpage with this script:

```
def randProxy():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/anonymous-proxy.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = []
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:20]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
            proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])

        try:
            t = requests.get("https://www.google.com/", proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, timeout=5)
            if t.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                proxies.append(proxy)
        except:
            pass
        
        proxy = proxies[random.randint(0, len(proxies)-1)]
        px={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}

randProxy()
```

but when i try i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\natan\OneDrive\Dokumen\Private-Folder\Project\WtD\main.py", line 51, in <module>
    randProxy()
  File "C:\Users\natan\OneDrive\Dokumen\Private-Folder\Project\WtD\main.py", line 33, in randProxy
    proxy = proxies[random.randint(0, len(proxies)-1)]
  File "C:\Users\natan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 339, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Users\natan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 317, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
```

Are anyone know how to fix this? i only want to get some random proxy

Comment: apparently `len(proxies)` is smaller or equal to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when the second argument is a negative. Look here.

```
import random
print(random.randint(0,-1))
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 226, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0, 0, 0)
```

So maybe find a fix for changing the last parameter to something positive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's actually because the first number has to be smaller than the second number. I just ran a program and had the same issue with random.randint(-50, -100) then switched the numbers and it worked